# Groupby and filtering in Pandas

Tags: python

For a dataframe like this:

```
    mpg    yr    name
0   18     70    chevrolet malibu
1   15     70    buick skylark
2   18     70    ford torino
3   16     70    chevrolet el camino
4   17     71    chevrolet chevelle
```

I can get mean MPG by year like this:

```
auto.groupby('yr')['mpg'].mean()
```

I tried the following to get mean MPG by year for chevrolet:

```
auto.groupby(['yr', auto['name'].str.contains('chevrolet')])['mpg'].mean()
```

However it creates an additional True/False boolean column, like so, where False is Non-Chevrolet and True is Chevrolet:

```
yr    name    
70    False   16.5
      True    17.0
71    False   NaN
      True    17.0
```

What I am looking for is:

```
yr    mpg
x     y
```

Can you please A) explain why my attempt didn't work and B) help correcting my mistake and explaining why it needs to be done that way.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We should filter before the `groupby`

```
auto[auto['name'].str.contains('chevrolet')].groupby('yr')['mpg'].mean()
Out[226]: 
yr
70    17
71    17
Name: mpg, dtype: int64
```

Your method create another groupby key with [True,False], then , pandas will groupby it and column `yr`

EDIT:

You can think this is what your data frame looks like

```
auto['yourkey']=auto['name'].str.contains('chevrolet')
auto
Out[228]: 
   mpg  yr               name  yourkey
0   18  70    chevroletmalibu     True
1   15  70       buickskylark    False
2   18  70         fordtorino    False
3   16  70  chevroletelcamino     True
4   17  71  chevroletchevelle     True
```

Comment: @user8834780 Yw~ :-) , if it help , can you consider accept and upvote it?

Comment: Need to wait 8 more minutes ;p But absolutely